# How to override dependency exclusions from a lib on an app that uses same version of dependency

Tags: java, spring

I have a lib where I've excluded dependency from an inhouse artifact and when I use the lib in my client application, it throws:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
```

How do I override this exclusion and not exclude this dependency in my app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it again as dependency in your pom.xml